# How to write a perl regex that puts a macro call around a literal string that doesn't have a particular call already around it?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file I need to go through that has literal strings scattered throughout.  Some have particular macros wrapped around them, others do not.  There may be more than one literal string on a line.  How do write a regex that would put a macro around those that do not have one of the particular macros around them?  The set of macros that can't be already wrapped is more than 1 but are limited (say 3).

So if the macro set is say FOO, BAR and BAZ and I want to wrap all other non wrapped literal strings with BAFF, I'd have:

```
JBAZ ( "str \" " ) BAZ( " \" boo" ) BAR ("boo") hello(" jazz ") FOO("FUN")
```

would result in:

```
JBAZ (BAFF("str \" ")) BAZ( " \" boo" ) BAR ("boo") hello(BAFF(" jazz ")) FOO("FUN")
```

I'm not even sure if it can be done in one regex, but extra points for those who do. ;)

**EDIT** Ok, so here's one attempt I've done:

```
my $qs = q("(?:\\\\.|[^"])*")
# Read in characters until it hits a double quote and then check if string before
# it is not \bFOO, \bBAR or \bBAZ.  Then read in quoted string and put BAFF() 
# around it.
s/([^"]*)(?<!\bFOO)(?<!\bBAR)(?<!\bBAZ)[[:space:]](?<!\))*\($qs\))/$1BAFF($2)/g

# Doesn't work since it'll find an end quote or a quoted quote and match replace
# from there:
# JBAZ ( BAFF("str \" ") ) BAZ( BAFF(" \" boo") ) BAR ("booBAFF(") hello(") jazz BAFF(") FOO(")FUN")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
my $string = 'JBAZ ( "str \" " ) BAZ( " \" boo" ) BAR ("boo") hello(" jazz ") FOO("FUN")';
$string =~ s/\b(?>FOO|BAR|BAZ)\s*+\(\s*+"(?>[^"\\]++|\\{2}|\\(?s).)*+"\s*+\)(*SKIP)(?!)|"(?>[^"\\]++|\\{2}|\\(?s).)*+"/BAFF($&)/g
print $string;
```

**Pattern details:**

There is two parts in this pattern, the first part will match all FOO BAR BAZ content and force the pattern to fail, the second matches the other content inside double quotes.

First part:

```
\b(?>FOO|BAR|BAZ)  # FOO, BAR or BAZ
\s*+\(\s*+"        # opening parenthesis and double quote
(?>                # atomic group that describe allowed content inside quotes
    [^"\\]++       # all chars that are not a quote or a backslash
  |                # OR
    \\{2}          # an even number of quotes
  |                # OR
    \\(?s).        # all escaped characters (thus \" is allowed)
)*+                # repeat the group zero or more times
"\s*+\)            # the closing quote and closing parenthesis
(*SKIP)            # define a point in the pattern where the regex engine is not
                   # allowed to backtrack if the pattern will fail later.
(?!)               # make the pattern fail (not followed by nothing)
                   # (You can use (*FAIL) instead of)
```

The second part is easy and use the same double quoted content description than the first.

```
"(?>[^"\\]++|\\{2}|\\(?s).)*+"
```

note: about this second part, and since the pattern begin to be a bit long, it will be interesting to use the `(?(DEFINE)...)` syntax and the `\x` modifier to make it more readable and to avoid to repeat this subpattern:

```
my $pattern = qr/
(?(DEFINE) (?<quoted> " (?> [^"\\]++ | \\{2} | \\. )*+ " ) )
    \b (?> FOO | BAR | BAZ )
    \s*+ \( \s*+ (?&quoted) \s*+ \)
    (*SKIP) (*FAIL)
    |
    (?&quoted) /xs;

$string =~ s/$pattern/BAFF($&)/g;
```

Comment: Ooooo, that's really close.  The only problem is that `$0` is being replaced with the name of the executable.  But $1 and $2 are not being populated. :(

Comment: Need to capture the 2nd quote and use that instead of $0.  Other than that, it works.  +1 for the explanation too.  Didn't know about `(*SKIP)`.  I'll mark it as answered when it has been corrected.

Comment: @Adrian: Since I don't know how to refer the whole match in perl in the replacement pattern, I have added parenthesis around the whole pattern. If anyone know how to do that...

Comment: It's `$&` to return the entire match.

Comment: @Adrian: Thanks, now it's working. You can have more informations about (*SKIP) looking for "backtracking control verbs"